# Simplification. Difficulty in detecting the series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!} = e^x$

Tags: summation

Any suggestion on how to simplify the following?

$$\sum_{m=k+1}^\infty \frac{((1-p)\lambda)^m}{(m-k)!}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $m-k=z\Rightarrow m=z+k$. Then

$$\sum_{m=k+1}^\infty \frac{((1-p)\lambda)^m}{(m-k)!}=\sum_{z=1}^{\infty} \frac{((1-p)\cdot \lambda)^{z+k}}{z!}=((1-p)\cdot \lambda)^{k}\cdot \sum_{z=1}^{\infty} \frac{((1-p)\cdot \lambda)^{z}}{z!}$$

Comment: Thank You @callculus

Comment: @user600927 You´re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Write out the first few terms:

\begin{align}
\sum_{m=k+1}^\infty \frac{((1-p)\lambda)^m}{(m-k)!}
&= \frac{((1-p)\lambda)^{k+1}}{1!}+\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^{k+2}}{2!}+\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^{k+3}}{3!}+\dots\\
&= ((1-p)\lambda)^k\left(\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^{1}}{1!}+\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^{3}}{3!}+\dots\right) \\
&= ((1-p)\lambda)^k\left(-1+1+\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^{1}}{1!}+\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{((1-p)\lambda)^{3}}{3!}+\dots\right) \\
&= ((1-p)\lambda)^k\left(-1+e^{(1-p) \lambda}\right) \\
\end{align}

Comment: I've tried this way, but..how can this eventually equal $e^{(1-p)\lambda}$?

Comment: It doesn't. Factorise out $((1-p)\lambda)^k$ and you should get it equal to $$((1-p)\lambda)^k(\exp{((1-p)\lambda)}-1)$$

Comment: I got it, thank You a lot

Comment: @user600927 I added some extra steps.

Comment: Thank You a lot @Botond